# Simple explanation of libraries, and how they are used for image use in C++

Tags: c++

I started teaching myself C++ a little while back, and I am wondering, how do you use images in your code, so I started digging around a little, and saw people talking about different libraries. Can someone give me a simple explanation of what the library is, what it does so that C++ can display images, why it is this way, and how would you use one?

I use flash and so to me a library is where all the images are stored and where you call them from using pointers, is this similar to what these 3rd party programs do to c++?

Comment: A library in C++ is conceptually very different to the "library" in flash - Essentially its somebody else's code that you can link to and use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess this question will be closed as too noob (sorry, see faq).

But to answer you question, library in C++ = "a collection of C++ functions and or classes.". It can either be in the form of a bunch of source code files that you just include in your program, or it can be in some OS specific format like a .so (linux), .dll (windows), framework (osx) along with header files you reference in your code.

Displaying an image in C++ is usually not so straight forward because it's different on every platform. C++ the language works anywhere but the libraries for each OS are different. How to open a window, surface, how to get input from the mouse, keyboard, screen, etc. In other words we can't tell you how to do display an image unless we know what machine you're on.

There are C++ libraries that try to hide some of these cross platform issues. Two that come to mind are SDL (http://www.libsdl.org/) and Qt (http://qt-project.org/)

SDL is probably more appropriate for games or similar. Qt is more appropriate for apps. Or least that's my impression. I've used neither.

Comment: `I'm going to guess this question will be closed` Yet you answered it anyway. This is why people post these things: because people like you encourage them. Please stop it.

Comment: I looked up the help. I didn't see an obvious "this question is inappropriate fit" (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The closest is "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." But this does directly involve tools used primarily for programming. Specifically C++ and it asks a specific question "How to display an image in C++".

Comment: And yet the very first thing your answer says is that this will be closed. Make up your mind. The real reason is that this is _waaaaaaay_ too broad and unclear. If you think it's "specific" then you are out of your mind. No offence.

Comment: My point about it will probably be close was people like you would want to close it. Since I couldn't find an objection in (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) I answered it. It doesn't seem too broad as the answer is small (ie: library = X, see SDL). If you think it's off topic maybe you should update the rules to make that more clear?